# CollabNet_Subversion with httpd configuration

Tags: apache, svn, httpd.conf, collabnet

I have svn installed and is accessible using `http://localhost:8080/repo`

But when I access the url in a browser it is opening without asking credentials.

I have cofigured the collabnet_subversion_httpd.conf file like below

```
<Location /repo>
DAV svn
SVNPath /path/svn/repos/repo
AuthzSVNAccessFile /etc/opt/CollabNet_Subversion/conf/svn_access_file
#Satisfy Any
Require valid-user
AuthType Basic
AuthName "Subversion repository"
AuthUserFile /etc/opt/CollabNet_Subversion/conf/svn_auth_file
</Location>
```

After this configuration, I think I have to restart the httpd to affect the changes. What is the command to restart httpd.

and also any other actions to take after these changes?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After restarting collabnet_subversion using the following commands, the SVN URL is prompting for credentials.

```
/etc/init.d/collabnet_subversion stop
/etc/init.d/collabnet_subversion start
```

Answer (score -2):

Change...

```
#Satisfy Any
```

...to...

```
Satisfy Any
```